# Which files to use out of the many included in JQuery mobile download

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have not been able to get an explanation of which files are needed in a JQuery Mobile Web site. The stackoverflow documentation on JQuery Mobile shows that there is one file for css and one file for js:

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
```

However, downloading the JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 package one ends up with many more. All files that have ".min" appended to the name of the asset, is a minimized version.

The standard download includes one js (the one mentioned above). That is required, as well as JQuery itself. At this date,  the latest jQuery that is compatible with jQuery Mobile 1.4.5:

```
jquery-2.2.4.js
```

(correct me if that is not true)

For css files standard download includes:

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.css
```

It appears to me that the first file contains all the rest. So that one can choose to include all at once with one file. The others, I guess, would be used if less code is wanted in a streamlined version of JQuery Mobile. However if one does not use jquery.mobile.css, which are needed in HTML at the top of the page?

If one uses ThemeRoller, jquery.mobile.theme.css becomes MySITE.css (whatever name was selected during the export process in ThemeRoller). If one uses a custom theme, then that theme css is needed, along with jquery.mobile.structure.css.

If one includes jquery.mobile.icons.css, does that in turn include in the external-png, external-svg, and inline-png files?

And what is "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.map" for and when is it needed?

That would all be good information for the documentation in stackoverflow.

I created a custom theme (mysite.css) in ThemeRoller so I include the following in HTML (in the appropriate link of script tag):

```
mysite.css
jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.css
jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css
jquery-2.2.4.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js
```

Is that correct?